# Have to resize the window to get it working

Tags: html, css, masonry

I'm using code herefrom

https://codepen.io/andybarefoot/pen/QMeZda

It works fine! Except from that i need to resize the window and then it worked properly. I wonder if this is due to Masonry is setting up my elements before my images have been loaded? How can I solve this then?

Screenshot: https://ibb.co/9v1GCp4

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="masonry/masonry.js"></script>   
        <script src="masonry/imagesLoaded.js"></script>
    </head>


$sql2 = "SELECT DISTINCT a.map_id, substring(b.post_content, 13, LENGTH(b.post_content) -14) AS post_content, b.post_title FROM wp_wpgmza a LEFT JOIN wp_posts b ON substring(b.post_content, 13, LENGTH(b.post_content) -14) = a.map_id WHERE b.post_title IS NOT NULL ORDER BY b.post_title ASC";
$resultSet = $conn->query($sql2);
?>


<div class="grid">
<?php

$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT a.pic, a.title, a.address, a.map_id, a.category, substring(b.post_content, 13, LENGTH(b.post_content) -14), b.post_title, c.category_name ,c.id FROM wp_wpgmza a LEFT JOIN wp_posts b ON substring(b.post_content, 13, LENGTH(b.post_content) -14) = a.map_id LEFT JOIN wp_wpgmza_categories c ON c.id = a.category WHERE COALESCE(pic, '') != '' ORDER BY a.id DESC";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo '

            <div class="item photo">
                <div class="content">
                    <div class="title">
                        <h3>'. $row['title']. '</h3>
                    </div>
                         <img class="photothumb" src="'.$row['pic'].'">
                            <div class="desc">
                                <p>
                                <strong>Name:</strong> '. $row['title']. '<br>
                                <strong>Coordinates:</strong> ' . $row['address'] . '<br>
                                    <strong>Country:</strong> ' . $row['post_title'] . '<br>
                                     <strong>Category:</strong> ' . $row['category_name'] . '
                                </p>
                            </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        ';
    }

} 
else {
    echo "0 results";  
}

$conn->close();
?> 

</div>
</html>
```